# What is סדר מעמדות?

Tags: tefilla, provenance

At the back of one of my siddurim, I found something called סדר מעמדות and it seems to have a part of the Torah and Mishnah, etc, that is divided from Yom Rishon (=Sunday) to Shabbos. What is the purpose of it, and its history?

Comment: shmuel, thank you for bringing your question to Mi Yodeya; welcome! I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 3):

Originally, there was less text, and it was said by the *anshe maamad*, the non-*kohanim* non-*l'viyim* who were on duty as representatives of all Jews in the *bes hamikdash*. By the time of the *g'onim* some people were saying it daily in commemoration (much as we say *korbanos* daily); more texts got added later. I don't think there was ever a time all religious Jews said it. ([My source.](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=926))